# Working with PEM files using python for SSL connection

Tags: python, ssl, python-cryptography

I have PEM file containing RSA Private key and list of certificates in it. I am using below code to separate PEM file to Key file and certificate file using pem package and then plugin them into flask server.

This code works, But I want to see if there is an efficient way of working with pem file using python?

Python Code:

```
from api import app
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import pem
from pem import RSAPrivateKey
from pem import Certificate
import os

Mylist = pem.parse_file(r"C:\Desktop\MyPEMFile.pem")
if os.path.exists("APIKEY.key") == False:
    for ele in Mylist:
        if isinstance(ele, RSAPrivateKey):
            f = open ("APIKEY.key","w")
            f.write(str(ele))
            f.close()

if os.path.exists("APICERTIFICATE.crt") == False:
    for ele in Mylist:
        if isinstance(ele, Certificate):
            f= open ("APICERTIFICATE.crt","a")
            f.write(str(ele))
            f.close


http_server = WSGIServer(("localhost", 443), app,keyfile='APIKEY.key', certfile='APICERTIFICATE.crt')
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use your `MyPEMFile.pem` as both `certfile` and `keyfile`. The underlying OpenSSL will just extract the certificates from the file for the `certfile` parameter and the key from the `keyfile` parameter. In short, throw away the PEM parsing and just do:

```
cert_and_key = "C:\Desktop\MyPEMFile.pem"
http_server = WSGIServer(("localhost", 443), app, \
    keyfile=cert_and_key, certfile=cert_and_key)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can get your answer here.](https://github.com/zaheebshamsi/Check-Certificate-Validity/blob/main/secCheckClass.py)   Else use the below snippet :

```
certs = pem.parse_file(file_path)  # using pem module
            for pem_certificates in certs:
                strcert = str(pem_certificates)
                # using pyOpenSSL module. 
                loadCert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
                                                           strcert)  # FILETYPE_ASC1
                issuer = loadCert.get_issuer()
```

Happy Coding!!!
You need to indent it. (Apologies)